# multiple Report for multiple Thread of one test plan in Jmeter

Tags: java, multithreading, groovy, jmeter, report

Is there any way to generate different report files for  a test plan having multiple thread.
my test plan has  1 thread Group
in that I have 5 Number of threads
for now I am using

```
jmeter -n -t emp.jmx -l empReport/TestReport.csv -e -o empReport/htmlReport/ -j empReport/jmeter.log
```

this logs all threads data in single file.
I want to generate different reports for every thread, Is there any way to generate differnet reports.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have a separate result files for separate Thread Groups you will need to add a [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html), for example [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) to each Thread Group and use different file names.

The Simple Data Writer listener configuration must match JMeter's [Result File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config), here are the defaults:

[image]

Once done you will be able to [generate a separate dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_only) for each thread group like:

```
jmeter -g /path/to/thread-group-1.jtl -o /path/to/thread-group-1-dashboard

jmeter -g /path/to/thread-group-2.jtl -o /path/to/thread-group-2-dashboard
```

More information: [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter)

Comment: I wanted different reports  for same test plan having multiple threads.My test Plan contains only one thread Group

Comment: In that case you need to add [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function as the request prefix or postfix so you could distinguish the results from different virtual users and then use [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) to split the .jtl file into several ones. The Filter Results Tool can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager).